# Is there Lorentz contraction in accelerated motion?

Tags: special-relativity

The usual Lorentz contraction is deduced for the case of a rod moving with linear uniform motion relative to an inertial frame but by a kind of "continuity reasons" it is hard to believe that no similar contraction happens in the case of accelerated motion and that's why I ask whether there is some generalization of the Lorentz contraction theorem from uniform to variated motion.

Such a generalization would be particularly welcome in the discussion of the relativistic rotating disk, where it has been argued by some physicists that Ehrenfest's argument [P. Ehrenfest, “Gleichförmige Rotation starrer Körper und Relativitätstheorie”, *Phys. Zeitschrift* **10**, 919-919 (1909). English translation, “Uniform rotation of rigid bodies and the theory of relativity”, available in the web at Wikisource] is not well founded because it rests on an application of the Lorentz contraction theorem in a situation where that theorem doesn't apply.

Two examples of such objections against Ehrenfest paper are by Varićak, in the very beginning of the polemics concerning “Ehrenfest paradox” (V. Varićak, “Zum Ehrenfestschen Paradoxon”, *Physikalische Zeitschrift* **12**, 169 (1911). Wikisource translation, “On Ehrenfest's Paradox”), and, much later, by Asher Peres [A. Peres, “Relativity in rotating frames” (2004). arXiv:gr-qc/0401043v1]

Comment: AFAIK Lorentz contraction is not a theorem or a law, it is just a consequence of SR, which indeed is easiest to explain for inertial frames. There are generalizations of course in the sense that relativistic effects in non-inertial frames is an extensively studied subject. Perhaps this can give you a starting point? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_coordinates

Comment: It's hard to know what to say about the Ehrenfest paradox because there is no disagreement about the prediction that special relativity makes for any experiment involving a rotating disc; there's just disagreement about which English (or German) words should be used to describe it, which is a matter of opinion. Generalizing Lorentz contraction has the same problem. If you describe a special-relativistic thought experiment to me in enough detail, I can tell you what value will be measured, but I can't tell you whether that value is a generalized Lorentz contraction.

Comment: The [clock hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation#Clock_hypothesis) is the assumption that “the rate at which a clock is affected by time dilation does not depend on its acceleration but only on its instantaneous velocity”. I have always made the similar assumption about contraction, at least in the case of linear motion, but the complications of defining extended objects in SR perhaps means I’ve been too cavalier.

Comment: @Amit For a mathematically minded person like me, a logical consequence of some set of assumed facts is a theorem. But I appreciate the rest of your comment.

Comment: @curiousket - sure, I was only referring to the convention / widespread terminology in my comment :) I guess you can take it as a theorem in the sense you are saying

Comment: @Amit you  are absolutely right. I guess no physicist calls "theorem" to the Lorentz contraction.

Comment: First ask whether a point particle (extremely small object) undergoes a change of path size or speed if moving in a circle in the frame of reference of the center of the circle, as a function of speed and radius.  The greatest problem is that SR applies only to non-accelerating objects.  There cannot be any way to tell which reference frame is moving.  When an object accelerates, that acceleration is truly experienced by that object.  The object's frame, and all inertial reference frames, can tell that the object really is accelerating.  This falls in the realm of general relativity.

Comment: In GR, acceleration to the right is the same as a gravitational field to the left with zero acceleration.  Just as a "point" particle would need a force pulling it toward the center of a circle as it moves in a circle, that point would need a force pulling to the right to keep the particle moving in a straight line when there is a constant gravitational pull to the left.  An object accelerating to the right to stay on a circle is like an object moving in a straight line at a constant velocity with an infinitely long massive rod to the left of the object's path.  I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @KenMellendorf, it is absolutely false that "SR applies only to non-accelerating objects".

Comment: You are correct when thinking in terms of momentum and energy rather than in terms of position and time.  I should have said that the standard Lorentz formulas do not apply.  A person has to get into energy, momentum, mass, and 4-space.  Also, experience from the point of view of an accelerating observer works differently than experience of an accelerating object from the point of view of a non-accelerating observer.

Comment: @KenMellendorf "experience from the point of view of an accelerating observer works differently than experience of an accelerating object from the point of view of a non-accelerating observer." - That’s my point. Special relativity deals perfectly alright with accelerated motions viewed from the point of view of an inertial frame. The problem, if any, is in describing the world from the point of view of a non-inertial frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the insight you need for this kind of question, I think it is best to consider the geometric presentation of special relativity which is offered by spacetime diagrams (Minkowski diagrams). In these diagrams you don't have to worry about Lorentz contraction or time dilation in the first instance; you simply plot the worldlines of particles. Such a plot would be four-dimensional if you could draw in 4 dimensions, but to get the idea it is sufficient to restrict to two spatial dimensions and one temporal one and then the diagram is 3-dimensional.

Where does Lorentz contraction come in? It is all in the way we now may choose to interpret spacetime as a set of spatial surfaces, one after the other. The central point is that one can legitimately pick any set of spatial surfaces as telling us what is the situation from one moment in time to the next, as long as they are all mutually parallel and all *spacelike*. Spacelike means the spatial surface is a set of events which can in principle be deemed to be simultaneous (in an appropriately chosen inertial frame). For such events no signals pass from one to the other because it would require fast-than-light signaling.

Having got that image in mind (I mean the image of a fixed spacetime, with worldlines of particles, and a set of parallel spacelike planes one on top the other) I can tell you what Lorentz contraction is. If we take a given spatial surface then the worldlines intersect that surface where they pass through it. Lorentz contraction is the observation that the size and shape of this intersection will depend on the surface you picked. In particular, it depends on the slope of the surface. In other words, observers in different inertial frames find that a given set of worldlines intersects their spatial surface in a way which depends on the slope of that surface and therefore on the relative motion between themselves and the particles whose worldlines we are considering.

That relative motion can be of any kind, including acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

Let us define the instantaneous speed of such rod that is undergoing uniform proper acceleration to be the speed of such inertial observer that observes every part of the rod to be at rest.

We know the aforementioned observer measures the length of the rod to be the rest length of the rod.

And now we just transform that length to whatever inertial frame we want. Now we know the length of that accelerating rod in any inertial frame.

Same definition works with constant coordinate acceleration of every part of the rod too.

Comment: "Let us define the instantaneous speed of such rod that is undergoing uniform proper acceleration to be the speed of such inertial observer that observes every part of the rod to be at rest." ---> a motion with uniform proper acceleration is too particular. I was asking about a completely general accelerated motion.

Comment: @curiousket More complex accelerations cause sound waves in the rod, thus making the length of the rod undefined. But don't ask me to prove that : )

Comment: I guess you're right.